# Accessing a ClaimsPrincipal in a WCF ParameterInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, security, wif, claims-based-identity

I am using WIF to secure my WCF service with claims-based security.  I would like to implement some simple attributes that can decorate service methods to specify the claims required for a particular operation.

I've started by implementing an `IParameterInspector` which I apply using a custom `IServiceBehavior` attribute:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
                ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
                ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {

    var parameterInspector = 
        new ClaimsAuthorizationParameterInspector(
           serviceDescription.ServiceType);

    foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers) {
        foreach (var endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints) {
            foreach (DispatchOperation operation in endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations) {
                operation.ParameterInspectors.Add(parameterInspector);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Inside the inspector I intend to look up my custom authorization attributes for the current operation, and then validate the claims required against the current identity.  However, the problem I am having is that I do not seem to be able to access the current ClaimsPrincipal from within the inspector.  I've tried inspecting:

- Thread.CurrentPrincipal (set to GenericPrincipal)
- OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal (set to null)
- ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity (set to GenericPrincipal)

I have configured the service with `principalPermissionMode="Always"`, and the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is always correctly set by the time I actually enter into the service code.

How can I access the correct `ClaimsPrincipal`, without having to manually create it from the incoming token, at this point in the pipeline?  Is there an alternative way I could implement these attributes instead of using a `ParameterInspector`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative way I could implement these attributes instead
>   of using a `ParameterInspector`?

Yes. There are specific extension points to handle security decisions. What you are trying to do is reasonable... you are just doing it in the wrong place.

Take a look at [How to: Create a Custom Authorization Manager for a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)